# C# Linq XML Extract Value By ElementName

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have the following sample MODS XML section:

```
<modsCollection xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-4.xsd" xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <mods version="3.4">
      <titleInfo>
         <title>PhD study</title> 
         <subTitle>trends and profiles 1996-97 to 2009-10</subTitle> 
      </titleInfo>
   <typeOfResource>text</typeOfResource> 
     ...
   </mods>
</modsCollection>
```

My Attempt:

```
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3";
        var test = modsDoc.Descendants(ns + "title").Single().Value;
        test.Should().NotBeNull();
```

[Source Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752505/linq-to-xml-extract-single-element)

The above gives me absolutely nothing! ***'System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements'***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your NameSpace you are using in your code is wrong. It should be:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3";
```

or if you want to avoid Namespace then try:

```
var test2 = modsDoc.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "title").Single().Value;
```

Edit:

Check this example:

```
XDocument modsDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3";
var test = modsDoc.Descendants(ns + "title").Single().Value;
var test2 = modsDoc.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "title").Single().Value;
Console.WriteLine(test);
Console.WriteLine(test2);
```

Output would be:

```
PhD study
PhD study
```

Comment: already tried that first suggestion let me try the second. - :(

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz, I have tried both the ways and it is working perfectly

Comment: The later approach seems to work after changing '.Single()' to '.FirstOrDefault'.

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz, that means you have multiple titles in your xml, Single will fail where there are multiple records or no record